# How to redirect to form submission page from controller?

Tags: url, redirect

I implemented a Form with a submission treatment by controller.

At the end of the treatment, I would like to redirect to the form submission page.

I tried several things :

```
$this->_redirect('*/*/');
```

and

```
$this->_redirectReferer();
```

I also tried to place the form submission url in the form by adding :

```
<input name="redirect_url" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $this->helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl() ?>" />
```

and in the controller :

```
$post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
…
$this->_redirect($post['redirect_url']);
```

But none of these solutions are working…
Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good guide with some options [here](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-redirect-functions/).
I normally use `$this->_redirectUrl($url);`

Comment: thank you for your answer. But It is not working for me…
I tried :
`$this->_redirectUrl('http://www.etoto.fr/sales/order/view/order_id/139/');`
and
`Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect('http://www.etoto.fr/sales/order/view/order_id/139');` ?

Comment: I think something might be wrong in your controller. Can you post the code?

Comment: I had an uncommented "echo" in my code, inducing a "Cannot send headers" error… 
working fine! thanks again.